# Why is child ViewModel instantiated when parent view is updated in SwiftUI

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I have an app built with SwitUI using MVVM, my parent view contains two views A and B, each one with its ViewModel, and B is shown conditionally. The thing is that when B *appears* and *hides* the whole parent view is re-instantiated, including A's ViewModel, which means that its data is lost.

Here is an example where View A contains a variable called isDataRequested, when the view appears it is set to true, but if ViewB is toggled isDataRequested will be reseted.

**Parent**

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ParentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent view")
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.showChildB.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Toggle ChildB")
            }.padding()
            ChildAView(viewModel:
                ChildAViewModel()
            ).padding()
            if viewModel.showChildB {
                Text("ChildB")
            }
        }
    }
}

class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showChildB = false
}
```

**ChildA**

```
struct ChildAView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChildAViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child A")
            HStack {
                Text("Is data requested: ")
                Text(String(viewModel.isDataRequested)).fontWeight(.black)
            }

        }.onAppear {
            self.viewModel.requestData()
        }.background(Color.green)
    }
}

class ChildAViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var isDataRequested = false

    func requestData() {
        print("request data A")
        isDataRequested = true
    }
}
```

I can instantiate "ViewModelA" inside "ParentViewModel" and data won't be lost but, is this the right way to do it?, what is the best practice? and most important, why does SwiftUI re-instantiate all child views instead the one that changes?

Comment: The `body` is computable property, so once called everything inside is `computed`. It is just a function, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body property is a computable property which means whenever a state (also observed objects as in your case) that is used inside it has changed it will be re-computed. So, if you need the data, you can move the model at the child view to the parent view and pass it to the child in order to keep the data when the body is re-computed.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state)